# Base table or view not found on fresh migration

Tags: laravel

I am trying to perform a migration and seeding the tables on a fresh app/server using:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'svadbenilokali.migrations' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:822
    818▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    819▕                 );
    820▕             }
    821▕ 
  ➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
    823▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    824▕             );
    825▕         }
    826▕     }

  i   A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your database migrations. 
      https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations

      +37 vendor frames 

  38  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I tried performing the migration and seed separately as well as removing auth from route without any success. The migrations and seeds are working fine locally. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you may have already run the command `php artisan schema:dump` before. If that's the case, please be aware that the generated file at `database/schema/mysql-schema.sql` does not include the `migration` table.

Delete the existing file and then run the command again.